# Appending to arrays in a Clojure loop

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to write a function to add up all the multiples of 3 and 5 between 0 and 50, but Clojure seems determined not to add the correct values to my list when I tell it to.

The `(conj toSum counter)` form is supposed to append the current number to the toSum array, and when the loop exits the `(reduce + toSum)` form is supposed to add everything in the array together.

As it stands, when the `reduce` function is called, `toSum` is always empty because the `conj` function isn't doing what it's supposed to do. I must have screwed up my logic somewhere, but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
(defn calculate [target]
  (loop [counter target
         toSum []]
        (if (= 0 counter)
            (reduce + toSum)
          (if (or (= 0 (mod counter 3)) (= 0 (mod counter 5)))
              (do (conj toSum counter)
                  (println toSum)
                  (recur (dec counter) toSum))    
            (recur (dec counter) toSum)))))
```

Comment: `toSum` is not an array, it's a `PersistentVector`, and `conj` only works on immutable types, it returns a modification of the input leaving the original unchanged (as @Lee notes in their answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conj` returns a new collection, it does not mutate the current one in place. You need to assign the new collection and recur with that:

```
(let [nextSum (conj toSum counter)]
   (println nextSum)
   (recur (dec counter) nextSum))
```

Answer (score 7):

A more functional and idiomatic approach:

```
(defn multiple-of-3-or-5? [n]
  (or (zero? (mod n 3)) (zero? (mod n 5))))

(defn calculate-functional [target]
  (->> (range 1 (inc target))
       (filter multiple-of-3-or-5?)
       (apply +)))
```

[`->>`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E) is the thread last macro, this macro takes the first form passed (the `range` form) and inserts it as the last item in the next form (the `filter` form) than it takes this new form and inserts it as the last item in the `apply` form. So this macro transforms the `calculate-functional` function in this:

```
(apply + (filter is-multiple-3-or-5?
                 (range 1 (inc target))))
```

In this case the thread last macro is not a huge improvement, but when there are more steps in your "pipeline" using the [thread macros](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/-%3e) can be significantly easier to read.

The `(range 1 (inc target))` form creates a [`seq`](http://clojure.org/sequences) starting at 1 and ending at `target` at the REPL:

```
(range 1 10)
=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

The next expression is `(filter multiple-of-3-or-5?)`,[`filter`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) keeps the elements of the sequence for which the predicate is true. And finally `(apply +)` uses [`apply`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/apply) to apply `+` to all elements of the sequence. You could also use `(reduce +)` here, I just wanted to show the very useful `apply`.

Comment: In addition, the other benefit of the above approach is that you can easily adapt the solution to accept the predicate used for the filtering, as another argument to the function, making the calculate-functional function a higher order function which can be used to sum a range which is filtered by different predicates